# How can I use the callback parameter in a button to get a user's preferences?

Tags: javascript, html, button, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am writing a firefox add-on that uses a button to take the users input and make decisions based on their response. Here's a section of my code:

```
catch (e) {
        var message = 'ALERT: going to a greylisted page'+page+""; //Alert needs editing                                  
        var nb = gBrowser.getNotificationBox();
        var n = nb.getNotificationWithValue('greylisted_page');
        if(n) {
            n.label = message;
        }
        else {
        var buttons = [{
                label: 'Options',
                accessKey: 'B',
                popup: 'Website Options',
                callback: //Is this where I should be implementing my idea
            }];

        const priority = nb.PRIORITY_WARNING_MEDIUM;
        nb.appendNotification(message, 'greylisted_page',
                              'chrome://browser/skin/Info.png',
                              priority, buttons);
        }
    }
},
```

[This](https://github.com/patthekidd/PETMISC) could be something that doesn't require all my code to find the answer.

Comment: I'll look more into this topic but this will definitely help you out: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-NotificationBox.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3926a0e9b51cebecf23c)

Comment: Wow! Thank you Ill see if your ideas work!